# Storage space and music

Tags: windows-10-mobile, music, storage, groove

I am pretty sure, I have never played or stored any music on my Windows Lumia 640 , but still the device storage in the settings sections shows that I have 1.2 GB of music on the device. On further digging it takes me to the groove page where I don't see any music that I have ever played. Why is it holding on to so much space on my device for music? I am an in need of space to download Windows updates and am being constantly reminded for it, but cannot download it. the phone comes with only 7.28GB of space to begin with, out of which 5.24GB is already taken up by the systems files. Of the remaining, now shows taken up by Music.

What shall I do to remove Groove and music (if any) from my phone?

Comment: You can't uninstall Groove Music, but you should be able to delete the songs using File Explorer (in Windows 10 Mobile) or the Files app (in Windows Phone 8). Also, check Groove settings to see if it's been set to automatically download any music.

Comment: Thank you Indrek! I used File Explorer and it turns out they were the podcasts. Got rid of them regained some space. Thank you again very much!